# Upload files using cakephp 3 and store it in a blob

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, blob, cakephp-3.0

I know that storing files in database is a little dirty, but I'm need to upload and store a file into a database BLOB and I haven't found any documentation about it and I haven't find any clue, so any help about it will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: Normally, in your upload handler, you get a reference to the temp file that was created, and move it to where you want. Instead, sounds like you want to use file_get_contents and write that data into the database. I don't think any of this is Cake-specific; perhaps that's why you didn't find documentation relating to this particular task.

Comment: So ¿there is no way of take advantage of scaffolding and/or ORM facilities? I feel Im missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing special that you'd need to do, simply set the data that you want to store in the appropriate entity property (respectively array key), either as a string, or as a stream.

`BLOB` columns will automatically be associated with the [**`\Cake\Database\Type\BinaryType` database type**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.12/src/Database/Type/BinaryType.php), where everything that is necessary for storing/reading binary data is being handled.

Here's an abstract example, showing possible use cases

```
$data = [
    'file_a' => file_get_contents('path/to/file.ext'),
    'file_b' => fopen('path/to/file.ext', 'r'),
    'file_c' => 'foo bar baz'
];
$entity = $Table->newEntity($data);
$Table->save($entity);
```

The read entities will always hold the data as streams, so you can use them with the [**Filesystem**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) and [**Stream**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.stream.php) functions, like

```
$handle = $Table->get(1)->file_a;
while (!feof($handle)) {
    echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
```

```
echo stream_get_contents($Table->get(1)->file_a);
```