# What's the best way to access a MySql BLOB in CakePhp 3.0?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

The manual says:

> Likewise, `binary` columns will accept file handles, and generate file handles when reading data.

I'm seeing it do this.  I have a table `users` with a column `my_blob`.  I did the bake all, so now I have a Table Users with an Entity User. If I get `$user` then `$user->my_blob` is a file handle (or stream) resource, not a string or something I can access directly. Reading the data may be easy enough `fread($user->my_blob, 256)`. But writing to it would be extremely cumbersome. I think I'd have to create a file to store my data then write to that or something like that.

How do I write to a BLOB field?

Comment: What are you trying to store? Actually I personally wouldn't probably store anything binary in a DB. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450432/sql-server-how-to-store-binary-data-e-g-word-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32298752/1392379

Comment: I just switched and used a text field instead.  Still I think it would be useful to know how to store data in a blob field in CakePhP 3.0.